# Multiple Views One Form

Tags: vb.net, forms, view

I'm looking to have a navigation pane on the left side of my form which will change the right side of the form accordingly. I could always use panels and store the controls on the panels but is there a better way to do this? A tab control would be nice but I wouldn't want to see the actual tabs ...

Is there a way to do this?

**Edit after seeing the answer:**

```
Dim uc As New UserControl1
Form1.Controls.Add(uc)
```

Will add everything in the user control to the form1. Alternatively, if I had a Panel, I could do:

```
Panel1.controls.add(uc)
```

That would add it to the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use panels, but you could also have your panes as UserControls and load them into a single panel instance, or even directly into the form.

Putting them into UserControls also means your form's generated class won't be cluttered with control members.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to agree with @Dai Here is a [great thread on it.](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?511530-Removing-Hiding-ALL-tabs-in-a-TabControl) It explains how to setup the panels in the ide.